# Spring Boot WebClient communication between two microservices: Body missing at recipient microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I have two Spring Boot microservices that I'm trying to establish communication between via http. They're both registered on Eureka, and I'm using Webclient to send a post request from service A to B as follows:

```
        WebClient webClient = webClientBuilder.build();
        System.out.println(request.getAuthId());
        System.out.println(request.getFirstName());
        
        Map<String, String> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
        valueMap.put("firstName", request.getFirstName());
        valueMap.put("lastName", request.getLastName());
        valueMap.put("authId", request.getAuthId());
        
        Mono<MessageResponse> createdUser = webClient.post()
                .uri("http://market-service/market/agrinet/auth/add-user")
                .header("language", locale.getLanguage())
                .header("accept-language",locale.getLanguage().toUpperCase())
                .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(jwt.getTokenValue()))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(valueMap))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(MessageResponse.class);
        
        return createdUser.block();
```

The Map approach is something I tried out based on another question here. I tried just sending the request object itself via .bodyValue() too. But both approaches have been to no avail, for whatever reason the body is just missing when the request reaches the other microservice. The headers are there and accounted for, however.

What am I missing? I scoured Google for answers but this seems like a pretty standard use case and yet something isn't adding up for me.

Comment: Figured it out. The receiving endpoint had a body param annotated with @RequestBody, but I used the wrong one by accident ( io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody instead of org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody)